# PHP set value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, key-value

i have a problem with [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach) in [php](/questions/tagged/php)
i tried to execute this code but at the end $part does not include **bought**
what's the problem?

```
foreach ($parts as $part){

     foreach ($boughtParts as $boughtPart){

            if($part['part_id'] == $boughtPart['part_id'])
                  $part['bought'] = 1;

     }

}
```

Comment: You can make it by reference or by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : `foreach ($parts as &$part)`

This will be passed by reference, but until now you were doing a copy.